# Web api emails from send grid are sending in spam folder

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am using send grid email to send web api mails using nodeJS.Though I am able to send mails successfully but they are landing in spam folder.

Earlier I have tried sending emails with php using phpmailer function and these emails are successfully delivered in inbox of user.

Below is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const env = require('dotenv').config();
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

var dburl = process.env.URL;
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

router.post('/users', (req,res) => {

  var data = {

      _id:req.body.id,
      Name:req.body.username,
      Email:req.body.email 
  };

  const msg = {

      to: 'example@gmail.com',
      from: 'test@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
      text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
      html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>'

 };

  MongoClient.connect(dburl,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, (err,client) => {


         if(err){

            console.log('Unable to connect with database'.red +err);
         }
         else{

            client.db("Example").collection("Users").findOne({_id:req.body.id},function(err,user) {

                      if(err){

                        console.log("Error:".red +err);
                      }
                      if(user){

                        res.send("User exists");
                      }
                      else{

                        var collection = client.db("Example").collection("Users");

                        collection.insertOne(data,(err,resp) => {

                             if(err){

                                console.log("Insertion error".red +err);

                             }
                             else{

                                res.send("User created");
                                sgMail.send(msg,(err) => {

                                        if(err){
                                         console.log("Error",err);
                                      }else{

                                         console.log("Mail sent");
                                         }

                                   });
                             }


                        });

                     }

                       client.close();
            });

         }

     });  

 });

module.exports = router;
```

Someone let me know how can I delivered emails to user inbox.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: may be because your from has word test in it.

Comment: No I have change it to  my original mail then too it is sending in spam folder.